# How to launch Microsoft windows' control panel from Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to create shortcuts in my Windows-Qt application to open the control panel items : devices and printers and network and sharing and maybe the control panel itself .I am yet to find a solution (windows 7 version).

Comment: Do you want the Windows 10 Settings app or the old Control Panel pages for the same thing?

Comment: windows 7 version..

Answer (score 6):

First, you could learn how to launch control panel applets using the command line (e.g. take a look at [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/192806/how-to-run-control-panel-tools-by-typing-a-command)). Then issue the same commands from a Qt app using the [`QProcess` class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html):

```
#include <QProcess>
void launch(QString command, QStringList arguments)
{
    QProcess::startDetached(command, arguments);
}
```

For example:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    launch("control", QStringList() << "printers");

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Why would you wrap a single function call in another function, when you don't do anything except pass the exact same arguments in exact same order? IOW, what is the purpose of having `launch` function instead of just calling the function everybody else would expect directly?

Comment: The OP could actually resort to a different implementation of the `launch` function, e.g. instantiate a `QProcess` object and call `start` on it, maybe connect its signals to some slots,  etc. or simply use the other overload of `QProcess::startDetached`. In my very short answer I gave the simplest example, just to show the core concept, which is expressed at the very beginning of it: see how to launch programs through the CL, then use Qt to launch them programmatically.

Comment: Great. Works like a charm.